# Local Git branches are not showing

Tags: git, github

Recently I have started working on a project, and all of the resources are on Git. I'm pretty new to this workflow so I have been taking it step by step. I have cloned the `master` branch and now am looking to work on and push a new branch, although I am having trouble with this and can't figure it out. I am currently running Git on Ubuntu 14.

Here is what I have been doing:

```
chrisevans@chrisevans-Inspiron-3542:~$ cd MSSM_Linkdn
chrisevans@chrisevans-Inspiron-3542:~/MSSM_Linkdn$ git branch
chrisevans@chrisevans-Inspiron-3542:~/MSSM_Linkdn$ git checkout -b home_prog
Switched to a new branch 'home_prog'
chrisevans@chrisevans-Inspiron-3542:~/MSSM_Linkdn$ git branch
chrisevans@chrisevans-Inspiron-3542:~/MSSM_Linkdn$ git push origin home_prog https://github.com/~~~~~/~~~~.git
fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in https://github.com/~~~~~/~~~~~.git
chrisevans@chrisevans-Inspiron-3542:~/MSSM_Linkdn$ git push origin home_prog
error: src refspec home_prog does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'origin'
chrisevans@chrisevans-Inspiron-3542:~/MSSM_Linkdn$
```

Note, it when I run the `git branch` command, no branches are listed. I also marked out the GitHub user names for security because I am not the repo owner.

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -v`? What happens if you just run `git push origin home_prog` without the extra url at the end?

Answer (score 0):

After your checkout, do `git fetch origin` or `git pull origin home_prog``

After you can try `git branch -a` this will show you all your branchs (local and remote)

Other thing, make sure that your remote is set correctly..so check with `git remote -v`, if not make sure to add - git remote add origin YOUR.git ([git remote documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote))

Maybe you did not setup well your git envirioment, so to guarantee that you are creating a local branch to origin repository do `git branch <branch-name> origin/<branch-name>`

If you like visual history display, use `gitk --all`

You can also check [gitk documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk)